How to upload image but NOT using form builder in Symfony 6?
I know there is a simple way to upload image in Symfony 6. In short - create form via form builder and then in the controller we just simply do:
$form = $this->createForm(MyClassType::class);
After form is submitted and valid we can get the image and (if we want to) move it:
if ($image = $form['img']->getData()) {
    $fileName = uniqid().'.'.$image->guessExtension();
    $image->move($imageDir, $fileName);
}

But in my app I can't do that. I've made plain form in html with input type=file. And I don't know how to access/move uploaded image that way. I can get only name of the file, not actuall image.
In my controller I created new object (which is in my model):
$uploadedData = new MyData();
$allData = $uploadedData->getMyData();
Where in method 'getMyData()' I'm checking which inputs (image is not required) have been filled:
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_FILES['fileName'])) {
              $image = $_FILES['fileName'];
    } else $image = "";
}

and return outcome (submitted data) as an array.
if I check result in the controller via dd($allData); I get (only showing image info):
"image" => array:6 [▼
    "name" => "test.jpg"
    "full_path" => "test.jpg"
    "type" => "image/jpeg"
    "tmp_name" => "C:\xampp\tmp\php89C0.tmp"
    "error" => 0
    "size" => 3909421
  ]

So it seems like all went ok, right?
But I can't access this image (or move it to the folder where it should be).
I tried access this image doing this ($imageDir is just a path to the desired folder):
if ($image = $allData['image']['name']) {
    $fileName = uniqid().'.'.$image->guessExtension();
    $image->move($imageDir, $fileName);
} else $fileName = null;

I got error: Call to a member function guessExtension() on string. I tried all of the keys. I got error every time. Even tried that:
$image = $allData['image']['name']->getData()
Got error: Call to a member function getData() on string. Other combinations also failed.
In other words - seems like image was uploaded (if that's the case I wonder where it is...) but I can't access or move it. Method getData() seems working only when we create form via
$form = $this->createForm(MyClassType::class);. But as I stated before - I can't create form that way here. If someone was wondering - my html form has needed attributes (method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data").
Any ideas?

I think you should try $allData['image']->guessExtension(). Based on your code, you trying access guessExtension() function file name not file

@Sivabalan
Suggested change didn't help. I still got error: 'Call to a member function getData() on string'. Although it marked my 'if' statement, so I can't say if your tip works...

$allData['image']['name'] is a string. In your if statement, you assign that string to $image.
if ($image = $allData['image']['name']) {

You need to fix your if statement. This code should move your file:
$uploadsDir = /path/to/uploads';
$tempName = $allData['image']['tmp_name'];
$name = basename($allData['image']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($tempName, "$uploadsDir/$name");

See the docs for move_uploaded_file here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file
If you need to  do any manipulation to the image such as resizing  or cropping etc you can try my image composer package here https://github.com/delboy1978uk/image

Yes. I get that. But how can I fix that? The whole problem is exactly that part. I can't access to this image (actuall image - not a name of the file as string). In other words I need a substitute of: '$image = $form['img']->getData()'. That is why I mentioned I can't use the first way (in my post) to upload an image. You understand what I mean or is still unclear?

Hi @Spowler I  updated my answer, hopefully this should help you

Yes! It works! Finally, goddamit! :) Thank you delboy1978uk!
